# get instant notification when a client disconnect from server socket in android

Tags: java, android

Hai friends i am new in Socket.
Now I implement a Chat app using Socket. I am testing with single Server SA and Client CA and CB. The Socket connection, chat and disconnect are working good.
But my problem is  when client(CA) disconnect from server socket server not getting instant notification. Once CA reconnect again with new name CAA server will notify CA removed, and CAA connected.

- my point is server must get instant notification when client CA disconnect socket.

**This is my server Activity:**

```
public class ServerMain extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;

    TextView infoIp, infoPort, chatMsg;

    String msgLog = "";

    List<ChatClient> userList;

    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private Timer mTimer1;
    private TimerTask mTt1;
    private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        infoIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        infoPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoport);
        chatMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatmsg);

        infoIp.setText(getIpAddress());

        userList = new ArrayList<ChatClient>();

        ChatServerThread chatServerThread = new ChatServerThread();
        chatServerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ChatServerThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
                ServerMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        infoPort.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                                + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                    }
                });

                while (true) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
                    userList.add(client);
                    ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(client, socket);
                    connectThread.start();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        Socket socket;
        ChatClient connectClient;
        String msgToSend = "";

        ConnectThread(ChatClient client, Socket socket) {
            connectClient = client;
            this.socket = socket;
            client.socket = socket;
            client.chatThread = this;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

            try {
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                String n = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                connectClient.name = n;

                msgLog += connectClient.name + " connected@" +
                        connectClient.socket.getInetAddress() +
                        ":" + connectClient.socket.getPort() + "\n";

                ServerMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                    }
                });

                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Welcome " + n + "\n");
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                broadcastMsg(n + " join our chat.\n");

                while (true) {
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                        String newMsg = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                        msgLog += n + ": " + newMsg;
                        ServerMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                            }
                        });

                        broadcastMsg(n + ": " + newMsg);
                    }

                    if (!msgToSend.equals("")) {
                        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToSend);
                        dataOutputStream.flush();
                        msgToSend = "";
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                userList.remove(connectClient);

                ServerMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (connectClient.socket.isClosed()) {
                            Toast.makeText(ServerMain.this,
                                    connectClient.name + " removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ServerMain.this,
                                    "not removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(ServerMain.this,
                                connectClient.name + " removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        msgLog += "-- " + connectClient.name + " leaved\n";
                        ServerMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                            }
                        });
                        broadcastMsg("-- " + connectClient.name + " leaved\n");
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        private void sendMsg(String msg) {
            msgToSend = msg;
        }

    }

    private void broadcastMsg(String msg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            userList.get(i).chatThread.sendMsg(msg);
            msgLog += "- send to " + userList.get(i).name + "\n";
        }

        ServerMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
            }
        });
    }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }

        return ip;
    }

    class ChatClient {
        String name;
        Socket socket;
        ConnectThread chatThread;

    }
}
```

**This is my Client Activity:**

```
public class ClientMain extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;

    LinearLayout loginPanel, chatPanel;

    EditText editTextUserName, editTextAddress;
    Button buttonConnect;
    TextView chatMsg, textPort;

    EditText editTextSay;
    Button buttonSend;
    Button buttonDisconnect;

    String msgLog = "";
    Socket socket = null;
    ChatClientThread chatClientThread = null;

    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginpanel);
        chatPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatpanel);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

        textPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.port);
        textPort.setText("port: " + SocketServerPORT);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
        chatMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatmsg);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);
        buttonDisconnect.setOnClickListener(buttonDisconnectOnClickListener);

        editTextSay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.say);
        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
    }

    OnClickListener buttonDisconnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chatClientThread == null) {

                Log.e("chatClientThread", "null");
                return;
            } else {
                chatClientThread.disconnect();

            }

        }

    };

    OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editTextSay.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                return;
            }

            if (chatClientThread == null) {
                return;
            }

            chatClientThread.sendMsg(editTextSay.getText().toString() + "\n");
        }

    };

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String textUserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            if (textUserName.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ClientMain.this, "Enter User Name",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            String textAddress = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
            if (textAddress.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ClientMain.this, "Enter Addresse",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            msgLog = "";
            chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
            loginPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            chatPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            chatClientThread = new ChatClientThread(
                    textUserName, textAddress, SocketServerPORT);
            chatClientThread.start();
        }

    };

    private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {

        String name;
        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;

        String msgToSend = "";
        boolean goOut = false;

        ChatClientThread(String name, String address, int port) {
            this.name = name;
            dstAddress = address;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(name);
                dataOutputStream.flush();

                while (!goOut) {
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                        msgLog += dataInputStream.readUTF();

                        ClientMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if (!msgToSend.equals("")) {
                        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToSend);
                        dataOutputStream.flush();
                        msgToSend = "";
                    }
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();

                ClientMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(ClientMain.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();

                ClientMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(ClientMain.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });

            } finally {

                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                ClientMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loginPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        chatPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });

            }

        }

        private void sendMsg(String msg) {
            msgToSend = msg;
        }

        private void disconnect() {
            goOut = true;
        }
    }

}
```